# C# ASCII or Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, ascii

hi im a beginner in programming and network development. i have a question regarding ASCII and Unicode encoding.

in msdn and other web examples do the following:

```
byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
```

is this because these code samples are old? shouldn't it be:

```
byte[] byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);
```

thanks for your input!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends - do you want the result to be in ASCII or UTF-16? Each is wrong when you want the other.

If you're talking some network protocol, you *must* find out which character encoding is expected by the protocol. Use the wrong encoding, and Bad Things Will Happen.

Of course ASCII has massive restrictions - it's very English-based (Latin characters only, no accents) but it's correct for some protocols. Others may use UTF-16 (Encoding.Unicode), UTF-8 or other encodings... or they'll let you specify the encoding yourself within the protocol.

Comment: im implementing both side of the client/server, so i get to decide.

im seeing Unicode as the choice as it is capable of accomodationg different languages. i maybe wrong!

Comment: @ikurtz: I'd suggest using UTF-8 instead of Unicode for most things, as it *usually* cuts down on traffic. There are exceptions to that (Far East characters often end up being bigger in UTF-8) and there are other downsides (you can't calculate the size of binary data directly from the number of code points) but it's generally a good idea IMO.

Comment: very good point concerning getting the message size! i understand why they use ASCII.

Comment: I second using UTF-8, it's almost always the best choice for storage and on the wire. UTF-16LE (which Microsoft very misleadingly call “Unicode”) is only really good for fast in-memory access. However, if you ask for `Encoding.UTF8` in .NET you generally get an unfortunate variant of UTF-8 that puts a bogus, troublesome BOM at the front of the bytes. To get clean UTF-8 you have to say `new UTF8Encoding(false)`.

Comment: @bobince: That depends on how you're using the encoding. Encoding.GetBytes doesn't emit the BOM, for example.