# converting array of Unicode chars to an array of ASCII characters

Tags: c#, arrays, unicode, ascii

So what I understand of this is that a Unicode character is two bytes long, so the first byte should be an ASCII token and the second byte should be another ASCII token. I have an array of Unicode chars and I want to convert it to an array of ASCII characters that will end up being twice as long as the original.

Comment: @Alan, that's not how it works at all. See [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042259/c-ascii-or-unicode) for a crash-course in question form. :)

Comment: You want to break the characters each into 2 bytes?  Or do you want to re-encode the string as UTF-8?  Or do you want something else?

Comment: (1) A Unicode character can be up to 4 bytes long (in both UTF-8 and UTF-16).

Comment: (2) ASCII characters must have the high bit set to 0. Unicode characters may have the high bit set to 1 in each byte.

Comment: @user319931: In (2), ASCII characters _are_ also Unicode characters. Just not vice versa. In (1) I think you're massively confused between Unicode and _encodings_. Unicode code points are just integral values which at present can be up to 0x10FFFF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joel says it best here:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

I highly recommend giving this a read.  It's the best primer on Unicode and character sets I've seen.

Comment: OMG, I am so tired of this! That article is a good argument for learning about Unicode, but too inaccurate to be a good Unicode intro.

Comment: Granted, it is a bit old.  Can you provide any resources that provide a better Unicode primer or describe the inaccuracies in this article?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to split the Unicode bytes into two ASCII characters.
The strings will be unrelated, the characters won't match at all.

Unicode characters are not made up of two ASCII tokens.

Unicode is a distinct encoding from ASCII.

But if you just want the byte data: `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);` is all you need.

Comment: Xaade. Thank you for your response. I am reading a text file that is in ASCII and I am using the ReadBlock method, which gives me a char array. Since my file is in ASCII, I thought that what this would do is take the byte data from the first two ASCII characters in the file and put them together into one Unicode character and then keep on doing that. Then my plan was to take each element and split it back up into its ASCII components. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Alan try using a StreamReader with Encoding.ASCII and reading the file with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method. With it you can specify the encodings from and to which you wish to convert your string (or array of chars).

As seen in their documentation there's this example:

using System;
using System.Text;

```
namespace ConvertExample
{
   class ConvertExampleClass
   {
      static void Main()
      {
         string unicodeString = "This string contains the unicode character Pi(\u03a0)";

         // Create two different encodings.
         Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
         Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

         // Convert the string into a byte[].
         byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

         // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
         byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

         // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
         // This is a slightly different approach to converting to illustrate
         // the use of GetCharCount/GetChars.
         char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
         ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
         string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);

         // Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
         Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", unicodeString);
         Console.WriteLine("Ascii converted string: {0}", asciiString);
      }
   }
}
```